# Combine value of unique keys in array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am a complete newbie at programming and am trying to create a function that combines the values of unique keys and then returns the highest value.

```
$arr = array(
   "Canada"=>500,
   "US"=>2,
   "Mexico"=>40,
   "Mexico"=>50,
   "US"=>170,
   "Canada"=>25,
   "Mexico"=>5,
   "US"=>300
);
```

Right now, if I print out the array, I get:

```
Array ( [Canada] => 25 [US] => 300 [Mexico] => 5 )
```

I want it to print out the following:

```
Canada = 525
```

I've tried during foreach loops, array_sum, array_map, array_reduce, but to no avail :(

Comment: Sure it doesn't work, array can contain ONLY unique keys. Each not unique key just rewrites previous one.

Comment: Okay, that helps a bit. But how do I fix it? Do I store each key that keeps overwriting to another array and then add them in an associative way? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You can make an array for each key, like ['Mexico' => [40, 50, 5]]

Answer (score 0):

As arrays always have unique keys I recommend you re-format your input array to an array of arrays like so

```
$arr = array(
  array("Canada"=>500),
  array("US"=>2),
  array("Mexico"=>40),
  array("Mexico"=>50),
  array("US"=>170),
  array("Canada"=>25),
  array("Mexico"=>5),
  array("US"=>300)
);
```

You can then parse this array in a loop - adding the values t0 `$counter_array`

```
$counter_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $arrays) {
  foreach ($arrays as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($counter_array[$key])) {
      $counter_array[$key] = 0;
    }
    $counter_array[$key] += $value;
  }
}

print_r($counter_array);


Array
(
    [Canada] => 525
    [US] => 472
    [Mexico] => 95
)
```

Comment: And what if I would like to keep my array as it is initially? Could I somehow split it by unique keys and make arrays within arrays, and then do a sum of array_column?

Comment: Your array as it is initially only contains the last reference to each country. It doesn't contain the previous elements as they are overwritten. ionafan2's answer is an alternative notation.

Answer (score 0):

Array Data Structure require unique identifier for each value. It's due to the way it's stored in memory.
Ask yourself: How would program distinguish between the two keys?

In your example. Let's say I'm trying to fetch a value of **$arr["Canada"]**.
You put 2 different values to that identifier (key). Logically, the last one will override the previous one. And that is what exactly will happen if you will try to instantiate this array.

In this case I would change the way of array instantiation to make it something like this:

```
$arr = [
    "Canada" => [500, 25],
    "US" => [2, 170, 300],
    "Mexico" => [40, 50, 5]
];

$result = array_map(function ($e) {
    return array_sum($e);
}, $arr);

var_export($result);

array ( 'Canada' => 525, 'US' => 472, 'Mexico' => 95)
```

Comment: And what if I would like to keep my array as it is initially? Could I somehow split it by unique keys and make arrays within arrays, and then do a sum of array_column?

Comment: What is the source of this data? Is it from a file like CSV? Or you got this from HTML page? Or XML document?